# JavaScript (WebClient) - recording and playing audio streams at the the same time?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, webclient, html5-audio

I am trying to create a webapp which:

1. records an audio stream from the microphone
2. plays the recorded audio stream and records **at the same time** a second stream from
   the microphone
3. merge both streams together ..

For (1) I am using `new MediaRecorder(stream)` etc.

For (2) I am using `new Audio(audio1.audioUrl).play() + new MediaRecorder(secondStream)`

For (3) I am using `new OfflineAudioContext(..)`

Step (2) works some times, some times not. 
It seems that`Audio.play()` **and** `MediaRecorder.start()` **at the same time** interfere with each other. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How come you have two streams from the microphone? Aren't these the same microphone inputs?

Comment: @Kaiido: I do *not* have two streams from the microphone (at the same time). I have one livestream from the microphone and a second stream which was already recorded (from a file). I want to merge the livestream from the microphone and the recorded stream from the file.